# Lebesgue Decomposition: A Counterexample

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am looking for a case in which Lebesgue decomposition of a measure fails.

More precisely, I am looking for some measure space $(X,\mathscr{M})$ , a positive measure 
$\mu$ on the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{M}$ and some positive bounded measure $\lambda$ on $\mathscr{M}$ (that is $\lambda$ is a positive measure s.t. $\lambda(X)<\infty$), such that
there exists no decomposition of the form
\begin{equation}
\lambda = \lambda_{a} + \lambda_{s},
\end{equation}
where $\lambda_{a}$ is a positive measure absolutely continous with respect to $\mu$, and $\lambda_{s}$ is a positive measure, with $\lambda_{s}$ and $\mu$ mutually singular.

Since the Lebesgue decomposition Theorem is stated under the hypothesis that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite, I suppose that such a counterxample exists (obviously $\mu$ must be not $\sigma$-finite in this case), but I could not find it.

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered that the counterexample I was looking for cannot exist.
Actually, the hypothesis that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite can be removed.
See Theorem 4.3.1 in Cohn, Measure Theory (by the way this is a wonderful
book on measure theory!).

Thank you very much for your attention.

Comment: Wait, the measure must be "finite signed, complex or sigma-finite positive". It must be sufficient to find a measure which does not relate to any of these cases.

Comment: Please, read carefully the question: I required $\lambda$ to a finite positive measure!

Answer (score 1):

The counting measure can not be decomposed with respect to the Lebesgue Measure.
Here is a proof:
[Show that the counting measure has no Lebesgue decomposition.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1177388/88132)

Comment: Please read carefully my question: I required $\lambda$ to a finite positive measure!!